# I want to make a class attribute into a tuple that receives its input through raw user inputs and saves the results into a file

Tags: python, python-3.x, object, user-input

**The following code works fine. But I want to make some modifications.**

```
from pip._vendor.distlib.compat import raw_input
class User():
    '''simulates a user for a social network or pc'''
    def __init__(self, first_name, last_name, username,location, interests):
        '''initialize attributes of user class'''
        self.first_name = first_name.title()
        self.last_name = last_name.title()
        self.username = username
        self.location = location.title()
        self.interests = interests

    @classmethod
    def get_userinfo(cls):
        '''each attribute of User is defined by a user input'''    
        return cls(
            raw_input("Welcome. PLease Enter Your First Name: "),
            raw_input("Please Enter Your Last Name: "),
            raw_input("Username: "),
            raw_input("What is your location? : "),
            raw_input("List some of your interests: ")
            )

    def __str__(self):
        '''returns all attributes of User as strings'''
        return str("User: " + self.first_name + self.last_name + 
                   "\nUsername: " + self.username + 
                   "\nLocation: " + self.location + 
                   "\nInterests: " + self.interests)

'''creates an instance of User object'''
user1 = User.get_userinfo()

'''writes each attribute of User into a file'''
filename = r'''C:\Users\User\Documents\dataset1.txt'''
with open(filename, 'r+') as file_object:
    contents = file_object.write(str(user1))
```

I want to make the parameter 'interests' into a tuple or a list. The user should be able to input many interests and decide when to stop through a flag such as 'active = True', and then finally return the results as a string to be able to write it to the file.

Comment: Please show us your attempts. [\[SO\]: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (mcve)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> I want to make the parameter 'interests' into a tuple or a list. The user should be able to input many interests and decide when to stop through a flag such as 'active = True'

I'm not sure how the user is going to set `active=True`, but the rest of that sentence just screams "I want a loop":

```
@classmethod
def get_userinfo(cls):
    first = raw_input("Welcome. PLease Enter Your First Name: ")
    last = raw_input("Please Enter Your Last Name: ")
    user = raw_input("Username: ")
    location = raw_input("What is your location? : ")
    interests = []
    print("List some of your interests (just type Return on its own when you're done)")
    while True:
        interest = raw_input().strip()
        if not interest:
            break
        interests.append(interest)
```

OK, that gives us a list, not a tuple. We *could* create a tuple by doing `interests = interests + (interest,)`, but that's clunky and inefficient. If you really need a tuple, it's actually simpler to just build a list and then convert it at the end:

```
    interests = tuple(interests)
```

And now we can pass all of those variables to the constructor:

```
    return cls(first, last, user, location, interests)
```

---

> … and then finally return the results as a string to be able to write it to the file.

Hold on; what kind of file are you creating here?

If this file is mean to be read and edited by a human being, and never looked at by Python again, that's easy. You can, e.g., just `join` them up with spaces, or commas, or newlines, or whatever you want. Or you can manually loop over them to format them more fancily:

```
def write_to_file(self, filename):
    with open(filename, 'w') as file:
        file.write('First Name: {}\n'.format(self.first_name))
        file.write('Last Name: {}\n'.format(self.last_name))
        file.write('Username: {}\n'.format(self.username))
        file.write('Location: {}\n'.format(self.location))
        file.write('Interests:\n')
        for interest in self.interests:
            file.write('    {}\n'.format(interest))
```

But if it's meant to be used for storing data to be read later by Python, you want to write things in a format that's meant to be parsed. Maybe add a method to serialize your objects to and from JSON, for example:

```
def to_json(self):
    return json.dumps({'first': self.first_name, 'last': self.last_name,
                       'user': self.username, 'location': self.location,
                       'interests': self.interests})

@classmethod
def from_json(cls, j):
    dct = json.loads(j)
    return cls(dct['first'], dct['last'], dct['user'], 
               dct['location'], dct['interests'])
```

And now, to write it to a file:

```
with open(filename, 'w') as f:
    f.write(user.to_json())
```

Comment: This is actually an impressive response, however, I don't quite understand where the loop should go in the code. Is it in the get_userinfo function? or outside?

Comment: @GilbertoRoblesSilva Yes, this is the `get_userinfo` method. I'll edit to make it clearer.

Comment: I forgot to add, the file is not to be read again by python. The goal for now is just to store the data produced form the program into the file. Later I will try to interact with that saved data but for now I'm just learning.

Comment: @GilbertoRoblesSilva The point is that formats meant to be pretty and human-readable are usually hard to read back into Python later, while formats that are meant to be read back into Python later are usually not that pretty. (JSON is a decent compromise, but it's still a compromise.)

Comment: Ok, so I did a couple tests to the exact code that you sent and the only problem is that the list is empty when it is returned. Also, is there any other way to end the code, rather than by typing in "return"? For example, Press 'q' to end.

Comment: @GilbertoRoblesSilva [Here's exactly my code running on repl.it](https://repl.it/repls/ExcitingOptimisticEngineering),and the list is not empty. Is that different from the code you're running somehow?

Comment: @GilbertoRoblesSilva Meanwhile, of course you can use any rule you want for when to exit. If you want "Press 'q' to end", just `print` that as the message, and do `if interest == 'q':` for the `break` instead of `if not interest:`.

Comment: Ok, so now that the code works, how would I access the information stored in the json methods?

Comment: @GilbertoRoblesSilva Don’t try to deal with the JSON directly; just create a new `User.from_json(j)` and use it the same way you would any other `User` instance.

Comment: So my problem is that I want to create another file called `user_login` and I want it to simply have the function of a login page, to check username. if the username matches then you can log in.                                                       `import create_user_frontend`

`prompt_username = input("Please enter username: ")`

`if prompt_username == user1["username"]:`
    `print("success")`      However, it just prompts me again for first name and last, instead of username.

Comment: @GilbertoRoblesSilva I don't understand entirely what you're asking, but it sounds like you want a dict where the keys are usernames and the values are `User` objects, so you can look up users and create new ones. And then maybe you'll want a function to save that whole dict to disk and load a whole dict back from disk, not a function to save and load individual User objects? This sounds like it's sufficiently far from your original problem that you may need to ask a new question.

Comment: Haha, yes it is. I will ask a separate question then. Thank you for leading me in the right direction!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I don't follow the flag part. But is this what you had in mind? You stop by just entering your items. * I will update if I misunderstood

```html
$ vi test.txt
$ python test.txt
from pip._vendor.distlib.compat import raw_input
class User():
    '''simulates a user for a social network or pc'''
    def __init__(self, first_name, last_name, username, location, interests):
        '''initialize attributes of user class'''
        self.first_name = first_name.title()
        self.last_name = last_name.title()
        self.username = username
        self.location = location.title()
        self.interests = interests.split(', ')

    @classmethod
    def get_userinfo(cls):
        '''each attribute of User is defined by a user input'''
        return cls(
            raw_input("Welcome. PLease Enter Your First Name: "),
            raw_input("Please Enter Your Last Name: "),
            raw_input("Username: "),
            raw_input("What is your location? : "),
            raw_input("List some of your interests: ")
            )

    def __str__(self):
        '''returns all attributes of User as strings'''
        return "User: {0} {1} \nUsername: {2} \nLocation: {3} \nInterests: {4}".format(self.first_name, self.last_name, self.username, self.location, ','.join(self.interests))

'''creates an instance of User object'''
user1 = User.get_userinfo()
print(user1)
```

```
$ python test.txt
Welcome. PLease Enter Your First Name: Hi
Please Enter Your Last Name: How
Username: Are
What is your location? : You
List some of your interests: Ball, Tennis, Python
User: Hi How
Username: Are
Location: You
Interests: Ball, Tennis, Python
```

Comment: Note: I'm not sure that *OP* wants a tuple with a single element (makes no sense).

Comment: @CristiFati yep, thanks for pointing that out, fixed in a way

Comment: Wow ok, so this works, and actually there are really no modifications to be made to the code. However, I am looking for something like a loop.

Comment: @abarnert might have a solution in that case